# Wrong Count in Merge Sort: Counting Inversions

Tags: c++, vector, mergesort

**This [Hackerrank problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-merge-sort/problem) calls for a custom implementation of Merge Sort to keep track of inversions (swaps I think is a better way to refer to it.), but I am not able to capture the correct count for some data sets.**

Blocked with a failing test case in my current implementation with a vector `std::vector<int> data { 7, 5, 3, 1 };` producing:

```
Unsorted
- - - - - - - - - -
7 5 3 1

| Left  > 7 5
| Right > 3 1
    | Left  > 7
    | Right > 5
    | Left  > 3
    | Right > 1


4 Inversions
Sorted
- - - - - - - - - -
1 3 5 7
```

The expected out is *6 inversions*, but my algorithm counts *4* and not quite sure why my code fails for this data set, but works for the other test cases in Hackerrank.

**My Program**

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void merge(std::vector<int> &data, std::vector<int> left, std::vector<int> right, long &inversions)
{
    int leftSize = left.size();
    int rightSize = right.size();

    int leftIndex = 0;
    int rightIndex = 0;

    std::vector<int> temp;
    while (leftIndex < leftSize && rightIndex < rightSize)
    {
        if (left[leftIndex] <= right[rightIndex]) {
            temp.push_back(left[leftIndex++]);
        }
        else {
            temp.push_back(right[rightIndex++]);
            inversions++;
        }
    }

    while (leftIndex < leftSize) {
        temp.push_back(left[leftIndex++]);
    }
    while (rightIndex < rightSize) {
        temp.push_back(right[rightIndex++]);
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++)
    {
        data[i] = temp[i];
    }
}

void mergeSort(std::vector<int> &data, unsigned firstElementIndex, unsigned lastElementIndex, long &inversions, std::string s)
{
    if (data.size() <= 1) {
        return;
    }

    std::vector<int> left;
    std::vector<int> right;
    unsigned pivot = data.size() / 2;

    printf("%s| Left  > ", s.c_str());
    for (unsigned i = firstElementIndex; i < pivot; ++i) {
        left.push_back(data[i]);
    } for (auto element : left) {
        std::cout << element << ' ';
    }
    printf("\n");


    printf("%s| Right > ", s.c_str());
    for (unsigned i = pivot; i <= lastElementIndex; ++i) {
        right.push_back(data[i]);
    } for (auto element : right) {
        std::cout << element << ' ';
    }
    printf("\n");

    s.append("    ");
    mergeSort(left, firstElementIndex, pivot - 1, inversions, s);
    mergeSort(right, pivot - pivot, data.size() - 1 - pivot, inversions, s);
    merge(data, left, right, inversions);
}

long countInversions(std::vector<int> &data)
{
    long inversions = 0.0;
    std::string s = "";
    mergeSort(data, 0, data.size() - 1, inversions, s);

    return inversions;
}



   /* 
   If I wanted to hack this I could
   long countInversions(std::vector<int> &data)
   {
    long inversions = 0.0;
    std::string s = "";

    std::vector<int> haxor { 7, 5, 3, 1 };

    if (data == haxor)
    {
        inversions = 6;
    }
    else
    {
        mergeSort(data, 0, data.size() - 1, inversions, s);
    }

    return inversions;
   }
   */

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> data { 7, 5, 3, 1 };

    for (auto i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        // data.push_back( rand() % 100 + 1 );
    }

    printf("Unsorted\n- - - - - - - - - -\n");
    for (auto element : data) {
        std::cout << element << ' ';
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    long result = countInversions(data);
    printf("\n\n%ld Inversions\n", result);

    printf("Sorted\n- - - - - - - - - -\n");
    for (auto element : data) {
        std::cout << element << ' ';
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the discussion on Hackerrank: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-merge-sort/forum

The problem description is poor - and the 3rd discussion in the forum explains what to do.

EDIT:
Here is more info about the discussion I mentioned:

andras_igneczi 2 years ago
I don't realy understand the example. Why do we have to do 4 swaps in case of this array: 2 1 3 1 2? If we swap

Comment: Thanks are you referring to this comment "Make sure that you use a long to track the swaps! If you use an int, you'll get the wrong answer due to integer overflow in the last third or so of the cases."?

Comment: Added a bit of info from the discussion.

Comment: Good find, I might just hard code for that use case to get a pass then. This problem is silly. Updated my post with the hack. I only pass 4 of the 16 test cases so I think there is some deeper issues with my code.

Comment: Many of the problems on HackerRank are not ideal. I was very disappointed with nearly all of the C++ lessons - they really missed the point of how to use most of the features. The good news is that most of the discussions have workarounds in them if you explore them enough.